# templated class that contains another templated class

Tags: visual-c++

I am writing templated classes, specifically  a  templated class that stores another templated class in an array. I am having trouble with getting the pair members thing1 and thing2 set. They are getting printed out as garbage variables.

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H
#include"Pair.h"

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Array
{
    template<typename U>
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const Array<U> &a);

    private:
        int size;
        T* tPtr;

    public:
        Array(int s);
        Array();
        ~Array();
        T& operator[](int sub);
        T operator[](int sub)const;
        const Array<T> &operator =(const Array<T> &);
        int getLength(){return size;};
};
template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array():size(0),tPtr(NULL)
{
}
template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array(int s):size(s)
{

    tPtr = new T [size];
}
template<typename T>
Array<T>::~Array()
{
    delete [] tPtr;
}
template<typename T>
T& Array<T>::operator[](int sub)
{
    if(sub<0 || sub>size)
        throw out_of_range("subscript out of range");

     return tPtr[sub];
}
template<typename T>
T Array<T>::operator[](int sub)const
{
    if(sub<0 || sub>size)
        throw out_of_range("subscript out of range");

     return tPtr[sub];
}

template<typename T>
const Array<T> &Array<T>::operator =(const Array<T> &right)
{

    if(&right !=this)
    {
        if(size!=right.size)
        {
            delete [] tPtr;
            size=right.size;
            tPtr= new T[size];
        }

        for(int i =0;i<size;i++)
            tPtr[i] = right.tPtr[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
template<typename U>
ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const Array<U> &a) 
{
    for(int i =0;i<a.size;i++)
    {
        out<<a.tPtr[i];
    }
    out<<endl;
    return out;
}
#endif

#ifndef PAIR_H
#define PAIR_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T,typename U>
class Pair {
private:
    T thing1;
    U thing2;
public:
    Pair(){};
    Pair( T thing1, U thing2) : thing1(thing1), thing2(thing2) {}
    ostream & display(ostream & out=cout) const;
};

template<typename T,typename U>
ostream & Pair<T, U>::display(ostream & out) const {
    return (out << "(" << thing1 << ", " << thing2 << ")");
}

template<typename T,typename U>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const Pair<T,U> & pair) {
    return pair.display(out);
}
#endif



#include "Pair.h"
#include "Array.h"
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename U>
Array< Pair<T, U> >zip(Array<T> & lhs,Array<U> & rhs) 
{
    int zipLen = (lhs.getLength() < rhs.getLength() ? lhs.getLength() : rhs.getLength());
    Array< Pair<T, U> >zipped(zipLen);
    for (int i=0; i<zipLen; i++)
        zipped[i] = Pair<T, U>(lhs[i], rhs[i]);

    return zipped;//return array object
}

int main()
{
    Array<int> a1(5);
    Array<char>a2(3);

    Array<Pair<int,char>>a3;

    for(int i =1;i<5;i++)
        a1[i-1]=i;

    for(char ch='a';ch<='c';ch++)
        a2[ch-'a']=ch;

    a3=zip(a1,a2);//this is the line where I seem to lose all my data

    cout<<a3;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**zipped** is a local object. When the scope is over, its destructor will be called. Also the destructor of the two Array class objects inside **zipped** object will also get called. In the Array class the destructor, you are deleting the dynamic allocation. That's why you are see the garbage values. :)